# Laravel, Eloquent, getting related items from a morph relationship (advice)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The title of the question may seem weird, but I'll explain it briefly. I'm not experiencing any issues yet, but considering any advice regarding the following approach.

I have the following tables:

```
articles
    hasMany(tags)

movies 
    hasMany(tags)

series 
    hasMany(tags)

subs (morph)
    media_id 
    media_type
    user_id
```

All of the first three tables have `many` tags, where the `subs` table have a `Morph` relation between them all.

The concept is simple, the user can subscribe to `movies` and/or `series` and NOT `articles`, let's say, opt-in a record from `movies`.

The following record will be inserting:

```
media_id => 1, media_type => movie, user_id => 1
```

Let's say we have 10K records like this in `subs` table. Now, I create a record in `articles` with specific tags. I want to notify all users in `subs`, who are opted-in `movies` and/or `series` that have exactly the same tags as the record I'm targeting from `articles`.

TL;DR: Notifying users that are interested in specific tags from movies or series.

To achieve this, I added the `morphTo` in the `subs` model:

```
public function media(){
      return $this->morphTo();
}
```

The logic is straightforward:

1. Get the article.
2. Get the `tags()` relationship and save it into a variable.
3. Check if tags are not empty, if not, continue
4. Get all the `subs`.
5. Get the `morphTo` relationship and get its tags.
6. Compare and continue.

   ```
       $article = MediaArticle::find($notificationable_id);
       $article_tags = $article->tags;
       $subbed_users = array();
       if (empty($article_tags) === false) {
           $subs = NotificationMediaSub::all();
           foreach ($subs as $sub) {
               $sub_tags = $sub->media->tags;
               foreach ($sub_tags as $sub_tag) {
                   foreach ($article_tags as $article_tag_title) {
                       if (strcasecmp($sub_tag->title, $article_tag_title->title) === 0) {
                           array_push($subbed_users, $sub->user_id);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           // continue here
       }
   ```

I find this approach really intensive and may cause the server to slow down a lot. Is there a better approach to achieve my goal?

=========================

2. Approach

I defined the `media_tags_relationship` as a Model, inside it:

```
public function media() {
        if ($this->taggable_type === AdminHelper::MORPH_MEDIA_TRANSLATION_MOVIE['original']) {
            return $this->belongsTo(MediaMovie::class, 'taggable_id', 'id');
        } elseif ($this->taggable_type === AdminHelper::MORPH_MEDIA_TRANSLATION_SERIES['original']) {
            return $this->belongsTo(MediaSeries::class, 'taggable_id', 'id');
        }
        return $this->belongsTo(MediaMovie::class, 'taggable_id', 'id')->where('id', 0);
    }
```

Now, I'm fetching the subs like this:

```
$article = MediaArticle::find($notificationable_id);
        $article_tags = $article->tags;
        $subbed_users_tokens = array();
        if (empty($article_tags) === false) {
            $article_tags = $article_tags->map(function ($tag) {
                return  $tag->title;
            });

            $related_tags = MediaTag::whereIn("title", $article_tags)->get();
            $related_tags = $related_tags->map(function ($tag) {
                return  $tag->id;
            });

            $tags_relationship = MediaTagsRelationship::whereIn("tag_id", $related_tags)->where("taggable_type", "movie")->orWhere("taggable_type", "series")->get();
            foreach ($tags_relationship as $tag_relationship) {
                $media = $tag_relationship->media()->with('subs')->get();
                if (empty($media) === false) {
                  $media = $media[0];
                  $subs = $media->subs->map(function ($sub) {
                      return  $sub->firebase_token;
                  });
                  array_push($subbed_users_tokens, $subs);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Utilize `belongsTo` and `$tags->with('subs')`.

You can fetch subs for 4-6 tags that you already took off article, then get every sub attached to it - way better of an approach, rather than fetching all subs and running a comparison.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with utilizing it. Should I include the `belongsTo` in the `Tag` model or where?

Comment: (Edit) Let me rephrase.
You should create a many-to-many relation. This way you can retrieve subs from tags and tags from subs.

Comment: The thing is, the user subs to the `media_id` and not `tag_id` or `tag_title`, therefore, tags don't play much of a role here.

Comment: So, you sub to media_id, which I assume leads to for example: `[movie]`.
Then that movies' tags are considered the tags to watch for?

Comment: Exactly. I'd sub to the `movie` itself and not the tag, because the tags are changeable (`movie => hasMany(tags)`).

Comment: Well, let's say you're interested in x movies and there's y article about that movie, how would I know that you're interested in reading that article? I can know that by checking if you're subbed to that x movie's notifications.

Comment: In my opinion, `x movie` should be a tag on its' own and article should include such tag: `movie: x`.

Comment: .. but yeah, it seems like your best bet is going through all media's that have identical tags and just notifying user about them.

Comment: That what would happen, the article will include the tag, which is exactly as the movie's name & keywords, that's why I'm checking for. I'm not experienced on this topic, but Netflix uses a better way to get related/similar/interesting media that you may like based on an item you watched. It may be from data analysis coming from other users but they sometimes send notifications regarding this.

Comment: Well, they most likely sub you to keywords (tags) - not media.. and if media gets' its' tags changed, they'll just remove the tag (which will also remove it from your sub) and attach new ones to your sub.

Comment: Hence why `$tag->subs` and `$sub->tags` makes more sense.

Comment: I've updated the OP with a different approach. Say I used the tags logic, this means that I will be inserting the tags' titles/ids in the `subs` table. Now, every time a media (`series` or `movie`) changed the tags (I need if tags did change at all), I'll need to remove the outdated records from `subs` and insert the new ones. This would affect min. 2~4K records in subs with inserting & deleting. It would happen more often too, because we will update the media.